# std::set<string, CustomComparer> cannot use std::find(...) with

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, find, set

I have the following code that cannot be compiled:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <functional>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct StringCompareNoRegister: public binary_function<string, string, bool> {
  bool operator()(string const& lhs, string const& rhs) const {
    return (_stricmp(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str()) < 0);
  }
};

int wmain() {
  set<string, StringCompareNoRegister> s;
  s.insert("hello");
  s.insert("STL");
  s.insert("Hello");
  wcout << s.find("Hello")->c_str() << endl;
  wcout << find(s.begin(), s.end(), "Hello")->c_str() << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

MVCPP v.11 CTP compiler yelling on the last line where `std::find` is used:

> Error 1   error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a
>   left-hand operand of type 'const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\xutility  3171

Why I cannot compile this code?
What have I done wrong?

UPDATE: Full compiler output

> 1>------ Build started: Project: Test01, Configuration: Debug Win32
>   ------ 1>  main.cpp 1>c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3171): error C2678: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion) 1>          with 1>          [ 1>              _Elem=char,
>   1>              _Traits=std::char_traits, 1>
>   _Alloc=std::allocator 1>          ] 1>          could be 'built-in C++ operator==(const char [6], const char [6])' 1>
>   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\exception(488): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::_Exception_ptr &,const std::_Exception_ptr &)' 1>
>   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\exception(493): or       'bool std::operator ==(std::_Null_type,const std::_Exception_ptr &)' 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\exception(499): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::_Exception_ptr &,std::_Null_type)' 1>          c:\program files
>   (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\system_error(419): or
>   'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const
>   std::error_condition &)' 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft
>   visual studio 11.0\vc\include\system_error(427): or       'bool
>   std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code
>   &)' 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio
>   11.0\vc\include\tuple(537): or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::tuple<> &,const std::tuple<> &)' 1>          while trying to
>   match the argument list '(const
>   std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>, const char [6])' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>              _Elem=char, 1>
>   _Traits=std::char_traits, 1>              _Alloc=std::allocator 1>          ] 1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility(3204) : see
>   reference to function template instantiation '_InIt
>   std::_Find,const
>   char[6]>(_InIt,_InIt,_Ty (&))' being compiled 1>          with 1>
>   [ 1>
>   _InIt=std::_Tree_unchecked_const_iterator,std::allocator>>>>,
>   1>
>   _Mytree=std::_Tree_val,std::allocator>>>,
>   1>              _Ty=const char [6] 1>          ] 1>
>   d:\docs\programming\test01\test01\main.cpp(39) : see reference to
>   function template instantiation '_InIt
>   std::find,const
>   char[6]>(_InIt,_InIt,_Ty (&))' being compiled 1>          with 1>
>   [ 1>
>   _InIt=std::_Tree_const_iterator,std::allocator>>>>,
>   1>
>   _Mytree=std::_Tree_val,std::allocator>>>,
>   1>              _Ty=const char [6] 1>          ]
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: Strange.  After adding appropriate headers, etc., this works for me with GCC.

Comment: It seems that something wrong with MVCPP11 STL realization (or compiler)...

Comment: Please post the full code. Is `string` really `std::string`?

Comment: Couple of things to try: explicitly convert `"Hello"` to a std::string in the `std::find` call. Pass your functor to the `std::find` call. As it stands currently, your functor will not be used in that call, it'll use `operator==`. Also, could you post the entire build output (there's some additional diagnostics that appear to be missing).

Comment: @NathanErnst explicit conversion didn't help. `std::find` always use `operator==`. The build output added to the original post.

Comment: @NathanErnst `std::find_if()` version with predicate works. But I would like `operator==` to be called. If I embed `*lhs == *rhs` code to the my comparison custom function object I again get the error. It seems that something with `string` `operator==` is wrong.

Comment: @DaddyM, I'll download MVCPP11 when I get home tonight and give it another look. Looking at the expanded error output, it definitely looks like a type mismatch (remember your allowed automatic conversions in template arguments is severely reduced).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ops.
The precise answer is that I've forgotten to add `<string>` header to includes.
String header contains external (non-member) `std::string` comparison functions like `operator==`, `operator<`, etc.

Thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 2):

std::find does not use custom comparators in the same way.  You need to overload the `==` operator.

The behavior is expected something like the below. Check [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) for the reference.

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
  InputIterator find ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& value )
  {
    for ( ;first!=last; first++) if ( *first==value ) break;
    return first;
  }
```

So you would expect something like this if you were using a custom type.

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const std::string &s_) : s(s_) {}
    std::string s;
    // used by std::set<Foo, Foo::Less>::find
    struct Less {
        bool operator()(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) const {
            return lhs.s.compare(rhs.s) < 0;
        }
    };
};

// used by std::find
bool operator==(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) {
    return lhs.s.compare(rhs.s) == 0;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    std::set<Foo, Foo::Less> foos;
    foos.insert(Foo("hello"));
    foos.insert(Foo("STL"));
    foos.insert(Foo("Hello"));

    std::cout << foos.find(Foo("Hello"))->s.c_str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << find(foos.begin(), foos.end(), Foo("Hello"))->s << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Linux just found the operator for std::string, so I couldn't test your specific behavior.  You may need to add some includes.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
```

Otherwise, defining your own is pretty painless.

```
bool operator==(const std::string &lhs, const std::string &rhs) {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Please, clarify: can I define `operator==(string const &lhs, string const &rhs)` somehow without the wrapper code?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, try changing your functor args to `bool operator()(const string & lhs, const string & rhs)`. See if that helps.

Comment: `string const &param` and `const string &param` are the same. But I've followed your advice and unfortunately nothing had changed :(